# How to make text height on pages the same and keep text on grid for book's page spread?

Tags: page-breaking, parskip, grid-typesetting

My project contains a lot of short subsections. After compiling some pages becomes longer than the others and also lost lines grid for page spread.

[image]

I've tried `grid` but not succeeded.
Sometimes subsection goes to the next page while there is a place for more one or two line on the previous page because compiler puts different space before and after subsections title and I can't control it.

Could anybody help to fix it?

```
\documentclass[a5paper,DIV=calc,twoside=true,fontsize=14pt,]{scrbook}

\addtokomafont{chapter}{\color{Maroon}}
\addtokomafont{section}{\color{Maroon}}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\color{Maroon}}
\usepackage{bookman}
\usepackage{typearea}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles % remove the default elements of headings and plain pages
\ohead{\pagemark}      % page number right aligned in the head of headings pages only

%\usepackage{stdpage}
%\usepackage{grid}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\clearpairofpagestyles % remove the default elements of headings and plain pages
\ohead{\pagemark}      % page number right aligned in the head of headings pages only
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{parskip}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Brill}
%\usepackage{libertinus}
\usepackage[english,ukrainian]{babel}
\usepackage[babel=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{chickenize}
\suppressonecharbreak

\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{auxhook}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage[all]{nowidow}
\usepackage{multicol}


\emergencystretch=10pt
\clubpenalty=10000 
\widowpenalty=10000
%\tolerance=9999
%======Move page numbers lower======

\ForEachLayerOfPageStyle*{scrheadings}
  {\Ifstrstart{#1}{scrheadings.head}{\ModifyLayer[addvoffset=.5cm]{#1}}{}}


%==============Asterix footnote==================
\usepackage[symbol*]{footmisc}
\setfnsymbol{wiley}

%===============Asterix footnote counter reset===========

   \makeatletter
\@addtoreset{footnote}{section}
\makeatother

%-------------Sections format-----------
\setkomafont{sectioning}{\bfseries}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{\chapternumdepth}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[font=\Large,
afterindent=false,
beforeskip=0pt,% skip before section heading
afterskip=\baselineskip,% skip after section heading
runin=false% freestanding heading
]{section}


\RedeclareSectionCommand[font=\normalsize,
   afterindent=false,
 beforeskip=\baselineskip,% skip before section heading
 afterskip=\baselineskip,% skip after section heading
 runin=false% freestanding heading
]{subsection}

\let\originalsectionlinesformat\sectionlinesformat

\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
 \color{Maroon}\Ifstr{#1}{section}
   {\centering #3#4}% centers section headings
   {\originalsectionlinesformat{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}% original definition for other section levels
}

  \let\originalsectionlinesformat\sectionlinesformat

  \renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
   \color{Maroon}\Ifstr{#1}{subsection}
     {\centering #3#4}% centers section headings
     {\originalsectionlinesformat{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}% original definition for other      section levels
  }

  %----------SNIPSETS------
  \newcommand{\Anagnosma}[1]{%
  \begin{center}
     \textbf{\color{Maroon}\normalsize #1} \end{center}}

  \newcommand{\AnagnosmaTwo}[1]
  {\begin{center}
     {#1} \end{center}}

  \newcommand{\redc}[1]{%
  \textcolor{Maroon}{#1}}

  \newcommand{\redcbt}[1] 
  {\textbf{\textcolor{Maroon}{#1}}}

  \newcommand{\Bukva}[1]
      {\lettrine[grid=true, lines=2]{\textbf{\textcolor{Maroon}{#1}}}}

  %=======Letrine with Gospel in two line=======
  \usepackage{varwidth}

  \makeatletter
  \define@key{L}{prelude}{%
      \renewcommand*{\L@ante}{%
          \quad
          \raisebox{-0.5\baselineskip}{%
          \begin{varwidth}[c]{12em}
              {\em\footnotesize\color{Maroon} #1}% changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
          \end{varwidth}}%
      \quad
      }%
  }
  \define@key{L}{prewidth}{\renewcommand*{\L@prewidth}{#1}}
  \newcommand{\L@prewidth}{\width}
  \renewcommand{\DefaultLoversize}{0.15}
  \renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\color{Maroon}{}}
  \makeatother
  %==========================================

  \usepackage{xparse}

  \NewDocumentEnvironment{prayer}{O{}mm}{%
    \lettrine[#1]{#2}{#3}%
  }%==================

  \raggedbottom
  %==================
  %\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}

  \parindent=0pt
  \parskip=0pt

  \begin{document}
  \renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}}
   \renewcommand{\labelenumiii}{\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}.\arabic{enumiii}}
  \renewcommand{\labelenumiv}{\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}.\arabic{enumiii}.\arabic{enumiv}}

  \begin{center}      

      \noindent\includegraphics[width=10cm,height=2cm]{example-image}
      \end{center}
     \section{БОЖЕСТВЕННЕ ТА СВЯТЕ\\ЄВАНГЕЛІЄ
    ВІД ІОАНА}
    \begin{center}Починаючи від святої та великої неділі Пасхи\end{center}
        \subsection[У НЕДІЛЮ ПАСХИ\\на Літургії]{У НЕДІЛЮ ПАСХИ\\На Літургії}

    \begin{prayer}[prelude=Іоана 1:1-17]{Н}{а} початку було Слово, і Слово було \mbox{у Бога}, і Богом було Слово.
  Воно було на початку у Бога.
  Все через Нього почало бути, і без Нього ніщо не почало бути, що почало бути.
  У Ньому було життя, і життя було Світлом людям.
  І Світло в темряві світить, і темрява Його не осягнула.
  Був чоловік, посланий від Бога; ім’я йому Іоан.
  Він прийшов для свідчення, щоб засвідчити про Світло, щоб усі увірували через нього.
  Він не був тим Світлом, але прийшов, щоби засвідчити про Світло.
  Було Світло істинне, Яке освічує кожну людину, що приходить у світ.
  У світі було, і світ через Нього почав бути, і світ Його не впізнав.
  До своїх прийшло, і свої Його не прийняли.
  А тим, які прийняли Його, дав їм владу дітьми Божими стати, тим, що вірують в ім’я Його,
  які не від крові, і не від бажання плоті, і не від бажання мужа, але від Бога народилися.
  І Слово плоттю стало, і оселилося серед нас, — і ми побачили славу Його, славу, як Єдинородного від Отця, — повне благодаті й істини.
  Іоан свідчить про Нього і викликує, кажучи: «Це був Той, про Кого я сказав: Той, Хто гряде за мною, став попереду мене, бо раніш від мене був».
   І від повноти Його ми всі прийняли, і благодать на благодать,
   бо Закон через Мойсея був даний, а благодать і істина через Ісуса Христа з’явилися.

  \end{prayer}

  \subsection{У СВЯТУ І ВЕЛИКУ НЕДІЛЮ ПАСХИ\\
  На Вечірні} 
    \begin{prayer}[prelude=Іоана 20:19-25]{Т}{ого ж} першого дня на тижні, як настав вечір і коли зі страху перед іудеями були замкнені двері дому, де зібрались учні Його, прийшов Ісус і став посередині і каже їм: «Мир вам!»
  І сказавши це, показав їм руки й бік Свій. Зраділи учні, побачивши Господа.
  Тоді сказав їм Ісус знову: «Мир вам! Як послав Мене Отець, так і Я посилаю вас».
  І сказавши це, Він дмухнув і говорить їм: «Прийміть Духа Святого.
  Кому відпустите гріхи, тим відпустяться, на кому залишите — залишаться».
  Фома ж, що значить «Близнюк», один із дванадцяти, не був з ними, коли приходив Ісус.
  І говорили йому інші учні: «Ми бачили Господа!» Він же сказав їм: «Якщо не побачу на руках Його рани від цвяхів і не вкладу пальця мого в рани від цвяхів, і не вкладу руки моєї в бік Його, — не повірю».

  \end{prayer}
  \subsection{У понеділок Світлого Тижня}
        \begin{prayer}[prelude=Іоана 1:18-28]{Б}{ога ніхто} не бачив ніколи; Єдинородний Син, що в лоні Отця, Той роз’яснив.
  І ось свідчення Іоана, коли послали іудеї з Єрусалима священиків і левітів, щоб запитали Його: «Ти хто?»
  І він об’явив, і не відрікся; і об’явив: «Я не Христос».
  І спитали його: «То що ж? Ти Ілля?» І каже: «Ні». «Ти пророк?» І відповів: «Ні».
  Тоді сказали йому: «Хто ж ти? Щоб нам відповідь дати тим, хто послав нас. Що ти кажеш про самого себе?»
  Він сказав: «“Я глас вопіющого в пустині: вирівняйте путь Господа”, як сказав Ісайя пророк».
  А посланці були з фарисеїв.
  І запитали його, і сказали йому: «Що ж ти хрестиш, якщо ти ні Христос, ні Ілля, ні пророк?»
  Відповів їм Іоан, кажучи: «Я хрещу в воді; серед вас же стоїть Той, Якого ви не знаєте.
  Він Той, Хто за мною гряде, Який попереду мене став, у Якого я недостойний розв’язати ремінь взуття Його».
  Це у Бетанії сталося, на тім боці Йордану, де Іоан хрестив.

  \end{prayer}
  \subsection{У вівторок Світлого Тижня}
    \begin{prayer}[prelude=Луки 24:12-35]{О}{дного разу} Петро, уставши, побіг до гробниці, й, нахилившись, бачить самі тільки пелени, що лежали, і пішов до себе, дивуючись тому, що сталося.
  І ось, двоє з них ішли того ж дня в село, що було стадій  за шістдесят від Єрусалима і звалося Еммаус.
  І вони розмовляли між собою про все те, що сталося.
  І було, коли вони розмовляли й міркували між собою, Сам Ісус, наблизившись, пішов із ними.
  Але очі їхні були стримані, щоб не впізнати Його.
  Він же сказав до них: «Що за речі такі, про які ви, ідучи, сперечаєтесь між собою, і чим ви засмучені?»
  І один із них, на ім’я Клеопа, сказав до Нього у відповідь: «Ти, мабуть, єдиний із тих, що прийшли до Єрусалима, хто не знає, що сталося в ньому цими днями?!»
  І сказав їм: «Що саме?» Вони ж сказали Йому: «Що було з Ісусом Назореєм, Який був муж пророк, сильний ділом і словом перед Богом і всім народом;
   як видали Його первосвященики і старійшини й начальники наші для засудження на смерть і розіп’яли Його.
  А ми сподівалися, що Він є Той, Хто має визволити Ізраїля. До того ж всього вже третій день сьогодні, як усе це сталося.
  Та ще й деякі жінки з наших здивували нас: вони, побувавши вранці біля гробниці
   і не знайшовши тіла Його, прийшли, кажучи, що і явлення Ангелів бачили, які говорять, що Він живий.
  І пішли деякі з наших до гробниці і знайшли так, як і жінки сказали, Самого ж Його не побачили».
  І Він сказав до них: «О нерозумні і мляві серцем, щоб вірувати всьому тому, про що сказали пророки!
   Чи не так же належало постраждати Христу й увійти в славу Свою?». І, почавши від Мойсея та від усіх пророків, пояснював їм сказане про Нього у всіх Писаннях.
  І наблизилися вони до того села, куди йшли; і Він показував, що хоче йти далі.
  І затримували Його, кажучи: «Зостанься з нами, бо вже надвечір, і день кінчається». І Він увійшов, щоб зостатися з ними.
  І було, коли Він возліг із ними, то, взявши хліб, благословив і, переломивши, подавав їм. 
  Тоді відкрилися в них очі і вони впізнали Його. І Він невидимим став для них.
  І вони сказали один до одного: «Чи серце наше не палало в нас, як Він говорив нам на дорозі і як пояснював нам Писання?»
  І, вставши в той же час, повернулись до Єрусалима і знайшли зібраних одинадцятьох і тих, що були з ними,
  які говорили: «Воістину воскрес Господь і явився Симонові».
  А вони розповіли, що було в дорозі, і як вони пізнали Його в переломленні хліба.

  \end{prayer}
  \subsection{У середу Світлого Тижня}
    \begin{prayer}[prelude=Іоана 1:35-51]{О}{дного разу стояв Іоан} \phantomsection\label{AndriyaPervozvannogoLiturgia} та з учнів його двоє.
  І, поглянувши на Ісуса, Який ішов, говорить: «Ось Агнець Божий».
  І почули два учні, як Він говорив, і пішли за Ісусом.
  Ісус же, обернувшись і побачивши, що вони йдуть за Ним, говорить їм: «Чого  шукаєте?» Вони ж сказали Йому: «Раббі (що в перекладі означає: “учителю”), де живеш?»
  Говорить їм: «Приходьте й подивіться». Вони прийшли й побачили, де Він живе; і в Нього пробули день той. Було близько десятої години.
  Один із тих двох, які почули від Іоана про Ісуса і пішли за Ним, був Андрій, брат Симона Петра.
  Він перший знаходить брата свого Симона й каже йому: «Ми знайшли Месію (що перекладається: “Христос”)!»
  І привів його до Ісуса. Поглянувши на нього, Ісус сказав: «Ти — Симон, син Іони, ти наречешся Кифа (що перекладається: “Петро”)».
  Наступного дня захотів Ісус вийти в Галілею, і знаходить Филипа і каже йому: «Йди за Мною».
  Був же Филип з Віфсаїди, з міста Андрія й Петра.
  Знаходить Филип Нафанаїла і каже йому: «Того, про Якого написав Мойсей у Законі і пророки, ми знайшли — Ісуса, сина Йосифа, з Назарета!»
  І сказав йому Нафанаїл: «Хіба з Назарета може щось добре бути?» Говорить йому Филип: «Приходь і подивись».
  Побачив Ісус Нафанаїла, який ішов до Нього, і говорить про нього: «Ось воістину ізраїльтянин, в якому нема підступності».
  Говорить Йому Нафанаїл: «Звідки Ти мене знаєш?» Відповів Ісус і сказав йому: «Перш ніж тебе Филип покликав, коли ти був під смоківницею, Я побачив тебе».
  Відповів Нафанаїл і каже Йому: «Раббі, Ти — Син Божий, Ти — Цар Ізраїля!»
  Відповів Ісус і сказав йому: «Ти віриш, тому що Я сказав тобі: Я побачив тебе під смоківницею? Більше цього побачиш».
  І говорить йому: «Амінь, амінь кажу вам: віднині побачите небо відкрите і Ангелів Божих, які піднімаються і спускаються до Сина Людського».
  \end{prayer}
  \subsection{У четвер Світлого Тижня}
        \begin{prayer}[prelude=Іоана Іоана 3:1-15]{О}{дного разу} чоловік один був із фарисеїв, Никодим ім’я йому, начальник іудеїв.
  Він прийшов до Нього вночі і сказав Йому: «Раббі, ми знаємо, що Ти учитель, який прийшов від Бога; бо ніхто таких знамень не може творити, які Ти твориш, коли не буде Бог з ним».
  Відповів Ісус і сказав йому: «Амінь, амінь кажу тобі: якщо хто не народиться згори , не може побачити Царства Божого».
  Говорить до Нього Никодим: «Як може людина родитися, бувши старою? Невже може вона в утробу матері своєї вдруге ввійти і народитися?»
  Відповів Ісус: «Амінь, амінь кажу тобі: якщо хто не народиться від води і Духа, не може увійти в Царство Боже.
  Народжене від плоті є плоть, а народжене від Духа є дух.
  Не дивуйся тому, що Я сказав тобі: потрібно вам родитися згори.
  Вітер  дихає де хоче, і шум його чуєш, але не знаєш, звідки він приходить і куди йде: так буває з кожним народженим від Духа».
  Відповів Никодим і сказав Йому: «Як може це бути?»
  Відповів Ісус і сказав йому: «Ти — учитель Ізраїля, і цього не знаєш?
  Амінь, амінь кажу тобі: Ми про те, що знаємо, говоримо, і про те, що бачили, свідчимо, а ви свідчення Нашого не приймаєте.
  Якщо про земне сказав Я вам, і не вірите, то як повірите, якщо скажу вам про небесне?
  І ніхто не сходив на небо, тільки Той, Хто з неба зійшов, Син Людський, що на небі.
  І як Мойсей підніс змія в пустині, так піднестися належить Синові Людському,
  щоб кожен, хто вірує в Нього, не загинув, а мав життя вічне».

  \end{prayer}
  \subsection{У п'ятницю Світлого Тижня}
    \begin{prayer}[prelude=Іоана 2:12-22]{О}{дного разу} прийшов Ісус до Капернаума, Сам і Мати Його, і брати Його, і учні Його, і там пробули небагато днів.
  І близько була Пасха іудеїв, і прийшов до Єрусалима Ісус.
  І знайшов, що в храмі продавали волів, овець і голубів, і міняльники грошей сиділи.
  І, зробивши бич з мотузок, вигнав із храму всіх, овець і волів; і розсипав гроші міняльників, а столи поперекидав.
  І продавцям голубів сказав: «Візьміть це звідси, не робіть дому Отця Мого домом торгівлі».
  І згадали учні Його, що написано: «Ревність за домом Твоїм з’їдає Мене».
  Тоді відповіли іудеї і сказали Йому: «Яким знаменням покажеш нам, що маєш владу так робити?»
  Відповів Ісус і сказав їм: «Зруйнуйте храм цей, і Я за три дні поставлю його».
  Тоді сказали іудеї: «Сорок шість років будувався храм цей, а Ти за три дні поставиш його?»
  Він же говорив про храм тіла Свого.
  Коли ж Він воскрес із мертвих, то згадали учні Його, що Він це казав, і повірили Писанню і слову, яке сказав Ісус.

  \end{prayer}

  \end{document}
```